# Derivation of 2D Trapezoid Rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

According to [this reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20191201035958/http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/SimpsonsRule2DMod.html), the trapezoid rule in two dimensions in a domain  $x\in[a,b]$, $y\in[c,d]$ is:

\begin{align}
\iint\limits_A f(x, y)\ dA &= \int\limits_a^b\int\limits_c^d f(x, y)\ dy\ dx\\
                           &={ \Delta x \Delta y \over 4}\bigg[f(a, c) + f(b, c) + f(a, d) + f(b, d) \\
&+ 2\sum_i f(x_i, c) + 2\sum_i f(x_i, d) + 2\sum_j f(a, y_j) + 2\sum_j f(b, y_j)\\ &+ 4\sum_j \big(\sum_i f(x_i, y_j)\big)\bigg]
\end{align}

Considering that the [trapezoid rule in 1D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Non-uniform_grid) is $\int f(x) dx = \sum_i {f(x_i) + f(x_{i+1})\over 2}\Delta x_i$ I tried to derive the 2D trapezoid rule as follows:

\begin{align}
\iint\limits_A f(x,y)\ dA &= {\Delta x \over 2}\int dy \sum_i f(x_i,y) + f(x_{i+1}, y)\\ &={\Delta x \over 2} \sum_i \int dy\ (f(x_i, y) + f(x_{i+1}, y))\\ &={\Delta x \over 2} \sum_i \bigg[\int dy \ f(x_i, y) + \int dy\ f(x_{i+1}, y)\bigg]\\ &= {\Delta x \Delta y \over 4}\sum_i\bigg[\sum_j f(x_i, y_j) + f(x_i, y_{j+1}) + \sum_j f(x_{i+1}, y_j) + f(x_{i+1}, y_{j+1})\bigg]
\end{align}

but this is significantly different from the result shown above so I'm looking for help to derive the 2D trapezoid rule. Thanks.

Comment: "the trapezoid rule in 1D is $\int f(x) dx = {\Delta x \over 2}\sum_i f(x_i) + f(x_{i+1})$...". Where did you get that? It does not look right to me. You should give half weight to the first _and_ last function values, full weight to all the ones between.

Comment: That was my mistake I have corrected the equation.

Comment: Note that most points $(x_p,y_q)$ are counted several times in your summation, when $i=p-1$ and when $i=p$, and when $j=q-1$ and when $j=q$. If you collect them together so the summation has a single term, you should get the formula in your reference.

Answer (score 4):

The 2D rule you found on the other Web page is for a uniform grid
(equal spacing between all the $x$ coordinates in one list,
equal spacing between all the $y$ coordinates in the other list).
With a uniform grid, the 1D rule becomes
\begin{align}
\int f(x) dx &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{f(x_i) + f(x_{i+1})}{2}\Delta x_i \\
&= \frac{\Delta x}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left( f(x_i) + f(x_{i+1}) \right)
&& \mbox{all $\Delta x_i$ are equal} \\
&= \frac{\Delta x}{2} \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(x_i)
       + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(x_{i+1})\right)  && \mbox{addition is commutative} \\
&= \frac{\Delta x}{2} \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(x_i)
       + \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)\right) && \mbox{renumber the index $i$} \\
&= \frac{\Delta x}{2} \left(f(x_0) + f(x_n) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(x_i)\right)
&& \mbox{combine equal terms.}
\end{align}

The last formula is the usual form of the uniform-grid formula,
except that people usually list the $f(x_n)$ term last inside the parentheses.
I arranged things inside the parentheses so that it is clearer that $f(x_n)$ is not part of the "$\sum$" sum.

Note that this is one of those cases where shorthands like "$\sum_i$" are likely to cause errors, because with the trapezoid rule it really does matter exactly where you start adding up the terms and where you stop.
You need to pay careful attention to the first and last index of each sum in order to make sense of the derivation above.

If you are not convinced by my formal manipulation of sums, try working out an actual trapezoid approximation with some number of terms, for example $x_1$ through $x_5,$ and see how it works.

The cited 2D rule is what you should get if you follow steps similar to the ones you attempted, but using the usual uniform-grid 1D rule in the form I derived above.

---

Another perspective is to recognize that your sum has a lot of duplicated terms, and to try to combine them somehow.
Recalling that the exact indexing of the sum in the 1D rule,
which you wrote as $\sum_i$, is actually
$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}$, and applying this to each of your applications of the 1D rule, the accurately indexed form of your trapezoid rule is

\begin{multline}
\iint\limits_A f(x,y)\,\mathrm dA = 
 \frac{\Delta x \Delta y}{4}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \Bigg[
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \left( f(x_i, y_j) + f(x_i, y_{j+1}) \right) \\
 + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \left( f(x_{i+1}, y_j) + f(x_{i+1}, y_{j+1}) \right)
\Bigg].
\end{multline}

You can combine the two sums $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}$ inside the brackets like so:
\begin{multline}
\iint\limits_A f(x,y)\,\mathrm dA = 
 \frac{\Delta x \Delta y}{4}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \Bigg[
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} ( f(x_i, y_j) + f(x_i, y_{j+1}) \\
 + f(x_{i+1}, y_j) + f(x_{i+1}, y_{j+1}) )
\Bigg].
\end{multline}

Write a sum of four separate double sums instead of one double sum of four separate terms:

\begin{multline}
\iint\limits_A f(x,y)\,\mathrm dA
= \frac{\Delta x \Delta y}{4} \Bigg(
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(x_i, y_j)
+ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(x_i, y_{j+1})\\
 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(x_{i+1}, y_j)
 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f(x_{i+1}, y_{j+1}) \Bigg) .
\end{multline}

Reindex to get rid of all those $+1$s in the subscripts of $x$ and $y$:

\begin{multline}
\iint\limits_A f(x,y)\,\mathrm dA
= \frac{\Delta x \Delta y}{4} \Bigg(
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(x_i, y_j)
+ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n} f(x_i, y_j)\\
 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(x_i, y_j)
 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} f(x_i, y_j) \Bigg) .
\end{multline}

Now let's look in the four double sums for equal terms that can be combined.

The term $f(x_0,y_0)$ occurs only in the first sum, so we only have one of those. Likewise we have only one each of $f(x_0,y_n)$ (second sum), $f(x_n,y_0)$ (third sum), and $f(x_n,y_n)$ (fourth sum).

For $1 < j < n - 1$, the term $f(x_0,y_j)$ occurs twice: once in the first sum, and once in the second.
Likewise, for $1 < j < n - 1$ the term $f(x_n,y_j)$ occurs twice,
and for $1 < i < n - 1$ the terms $f(x_i,y_0)$ and $f(x_i,y_n)$ occur twice each.

But when $1 < i < n - 1$ and $1 < j < n - 1$, the term $f(x_i,y_j)$
occurs in all four sums, that is, four times.

Adding up the terms that occur only once, we have

$$ f(x_0,y_0) + f(x_n,y_0) + f(x_0,y_n) + f(x_n,y_n)
   = f(a,c) + f(b,c) + f(a,d) + f(b,d). $$

Adding up the terms that occur twice, we have
\begin{multline}
2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(x_i,y_0)
+ 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(x_i,y_n)
+ 2 \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} f(x_0,y_j)
+ 2 \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} f(x_n,y_j) = \\
2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(x_i,c)
+ 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(x_i,d)
+ 2 \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} f(a,y_j)
+ 2 \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} f(b,y_j).
\end{multline}

Finally, for all the terms that occur four times each, we have
$$
4 \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(x_i,y_j).
$$

Add those all together:

\begin{align}
\iint\limits_A f(x,y)\,\mathrm dA
= \frac{\Delta x \Delta y}{4} \Bigg(
f(a,c) &+ f(b,c) + f(a,d) + f(b,d) \\
&+ 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(x_i,c)
+ 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(x_i,d)\\
&+ 2 \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} f(a,y_j)
+ 2 \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} f(b,y_j)\\
&+ 4 \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(x_i,y_j) \Bigg),
\end{align}

which is the same as the formula you found in
[your reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20191201035958/http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/SimpsonsRule2DMod.html),
including the exact starting and stopping values of $i$ and $j$
in the sums as shown in that document.

So your formula in fact is exactly equal to the one you found
in the reference document; you just added up the terms in a different way.

Comment: Your answer has been quite helpful. However, shouldn't the last equation have $f(x_0)$  instead of $f(x_1)$? Also I think in the third equality the distributive property was used, not commutative...

Comment: Yes, it should be $x_0.$ The distributive property is (quietly) invoked between the first and second lines of the list of equations in order to take the $\Delta x$ out of each individual term and make it multiply the whole sum. Once it's out, it stays out and does not distribute again. The individual $f(x_\square)$ terms within the sum get added in a different order on line 3 than on line 2, however.